# Adobe Illustrator Error loading plugins

Tags: visual-c++, plugins, adobe-illustrator

I was following a simple Hello World tutorial given in adobe illustrator CS4 sdk package.

I followed all the steps and wrote C++ code in Visual studio 2013 and it built successfully without any errors and 2 files were generated *.aip and *.ilk.

Now the tutorial said to place the plug-in binary file in the illustrator's plugin folder.

It didn't specify which file is the binary file (I assumed the *.aip file) and the plugin path for illustrator (I think this is the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS4\Plug-ins")

Now when I launch the adobe illustrator application, on startup I get the following error.

Error loading plugins.
*.aip

Can anyone tell me what's wrong. Is the path wrong ? Is the file wrong ? or is there some obvious step that I am missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution. The problem was the tutorial is specific for 32 bit system and doesn't mention 1 change we have to make for running our 64 bit plugin.

I added the x64 platform to my project. Here are the steps:

Select the "Build | Configuration Manager..." menu item.

In the "Configuration Manager" dialog, choose "" from the "Active solution platform" drop down.

In the "New Solution Platform" dialog, "x64" should already be selected in the top drop down and "win32" should be selected in the "Copy settings from:" drop down (and the "Create new project platforms" check box should be checked. Click Ok and you can now build 64 bit versions using the x64 platform.

Answer (score 1):

> Browse to this folder:
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS5\Support Files\Required
> ```
>
> look for a duplicate `ADMplugin.apl` file (probably named `ADMplugin(1).apl`) and delete it.
>
> AI should start normally.
>
> I had the control panel.aip issue and this worked for me. I tracked down the problem by temporarily removing the plug-ins folder from this directory...
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS5
> ```
>
> ...then starting Illustrator. The program crashes on startup. When the crash report appears, looking at the content of crash report points to `ADMplugin.apl`.

Source: http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/discussions/illustrator-cs5-error-loading-plugins/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't leave unrelated links as a signature to your post; those belong in your profile.