# Error loading plugin in Adobe Illustrator 2018

Tags: c++, windows, plugins, adobe-illustrator

A problem with an Illustrator plugin (aip file) that I develop. It's already posted in the Adobe forums, but looks like noone can help me there, and after lots of debugging, we also realised that it's not Adobe specific.
https://forums.adobe.com/message/10474362#10474362

A plugin that runs fine on all Windows 10 64 dev machines doesn't work on a production machine, although it's also Windows 10 64.

The only error that we get is 'Error loading plugin' (but in Spanish, but the language can't be a problem, can it?).

**We found out this**:  ScriptMessage.aip imports functions from msvcp140d.dll, vcruntime140d.dll, ucrtbased.dll, vcruntime140.dll. It is part of Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable.

So this made me think that the problem is using VisualStudio 2017. So I installed VS2015 and compiled an original (untouched) example from Adobe with that (using Release x64 configuration). But the problem persists.

I also tried all the steps from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120138/adobe-illustrator-error-loading-plugins) thread, but no...

Any idea how to analyse the problem further, or what I could try?

Best regards,
Stefan

Comment: The `msvcp140d.dll` is part of the DEBUG facilities of Visual Studio.  The `d` in the name means "debug".  (Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 Debug.)  It's not for redistribution.  The ScriptMessage.aip was not compiled for release.

Comment: Ok thanks. That this dll is being loaded is part of the debugging results. 
Afterwards I made the trials with Release builds, and I still have the loading issue.

Comment: Make sure your deployment executables do not have dependencies on the debug DLLs.  The debug DLLs are not redistributable.  If that doesn't get you past the problem, may be useful to look very carefully at all the DLL dependencies involved.  [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is a good tool for sleuthing dependency problems (if that is still the problem).

Comment: These are very good tips! I just don't understand how the original Adobe examples bring these problems.

Comment: I can only assume the Adobe Illustrator folks published an example project now based on Visual Studio 2017, and they had left DEBUG as the target.  Which would only work on the developer's machine, because that has VS2017 installed, which means the non-re-distributable DEBUG DLLs are installed.  So it would appear to work okay on the devs machine, but not when rolled out into production (on non-dev machines).

Comment: The platform toolset of the original examples is for 2015. And in all the documentation, they still refer to VS2015. 
But that they left DEBUG as the target can be fixed by changing to RELEASE or not? Or are there more settings involved that can lead to referencing debug assemblies?